# Can the parameters be different when the mean and variance are the same?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

im korean. Please understand even if I'm not good at English.

Q.

If two variables from same type of distribution like exponential, normal, ...,
and if they have same means, and same variances, then two parameters always same?

e.g. Binomial(n,p)

$X$ ~ binomial($n_{1}$,$p_{1}$), $Y$ ~ binomial($n_{2}$,$p_{2}$)  (they have same type of distribution, not sure $n1 = n2$ and $p1 = p2$)

Let $\mu_{X}$ and $\mu_{Y}$ are same,  $Var(X)$ and $Var(Y)$ are same also.

then,  always $n1 = n2$ and $p1 = p2$?

i think it is correct for this example(binomial), but all of continous pdf also correct?

Comment: It's not true anymore if your sample space $\Omega$ is big enough, i.e. contains sets of measure zero. You can just alter your random Variable $X$ on a set of measure zero and still get the same distribution function and therefore the same mean and variance.

Comment: For most well-known two-parameter families of distributions, there is a $1-1$ relationship between those two parameters and the mean and variance, though not for example if the variance is infinite; for Gaussian distributions the two parameters are the mean and variance.  But not for families of distributions with three or more parameters, such as for example triangular distributions